# Calling `accept` syscall in loop creates corrupted sockets

Tags: c, http, networking, pthreads, webserver

I'm trying to build myself a web app in C. So far, I've got the HTTP server working, but for some reason, when I have things like HTML files that require other CSS, and JavaScript files, the browser (Firefox) will do several requests very fast, causing the socket connection between the server and the client  to become corrupted. I've tried many different things to get the HTTP server to work without generating corrupted TCP connections.

Currently, I have a loop that calls `accept`, and creates a new thread for each new connection:

```c
for(;;)
{
    int newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&host_addr, (socklen_t *)&host_addrlen);
    if(newsockfd < 0)
    {
        sendf(stderr, LOG_ERROR, "Failed to accept connection...\n");
        continue;
    }
    pthread_t thread;
    if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL, handler, (void *)&newsockfd) != 0)
    {
        sendf(stderr, LOG_ERROR, "Failed to create a new thread...\n");
        return -4;
    }
}
```

I create the thread, while sending the socket file descriptor (that represents the new connection between the client and server) to the new thread.

The function that handles the newly created thread looks like this:

```c
void * handler(void * argument)
{
    int sockfd = *((int *)argument);

    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int client_addrlen = sizeof(client_addr);

    int sockn = getpeername(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, (socklen_t *)&client_addrlen);
    if(sockn < 0)
    {
        sendf(stderr, LOG_ERROR, "Failed to get client's address, got \x1b[35msockn\x1b[0m \x1b[33;3m%d\x1b[0m...\n", sockn);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    char * input = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER_SIZE);

    int valread = read(sockfd, input, BUFFER_SIZE);
    if(valread < 0)
    {
        sendf(stderr, LOG_ERROR, "Failed to read from socket, got \x1b[35mvalread\x1b[0m \x1b[33;3m%d\x1b[0m...\n", valread);
        free(input);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    char * method = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER_SIZE);
    char * url = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER_SIZE);
    char * version = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER_SIZE);
    sscanf(input, "%s %s %s", method, url, version);
    sendf(stdout, LOG_DEBUG, "Client \x1b[33;3m%s:%u\x1b[0m has sent a \x1b[33;3m%s\x1b[0m request to \x1b[33;3m%s\x1b[0m!\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port), method, url);

    ...
```

When the connection is corrupted, I get:

```
[ERROR]: Failed to get client's address, got sockn -1...
```

With some debugging tools, I then check and see that the first bytes in `method`, `url`, and `verison` are set to `NULL`. The function `getpeername` also returns -1.
The function `sendf` is just basic printf-like function, but doesn't seem to be the cause of the issue.

Anyone spot any issue here?

Comment: Doing 'several requests very fast' does not 'cause socket connections to become corrupted.' You have a bug in your code. Don't kid yourself it's someone else's fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing your thread `handler` a pointer to a *local variable* `newsockfd` which is no longer in scope by the time the thread begins running.

You need to either:

- allocate a new `int` dynamically which the `handler` will free, eg:

```
int *newsockfd = malloc(sizeof(int));
if (!newsockfd) { ... }
*newsockfd = ...;
...
pthread_t thread;
if (pthread_create(..., newsockfd) != 0) {
    free(newsockfd);
    ...
}
```

```
void * handler(void * argument)
{
    int *sockfd = (int*)argument;
    ...
    free(sockfd);
}
```

- simply pass the *value* of `newsockfd` instead of a *pointer* to it, eg:

```
int newsockfd = ...;
...
pthread_t thread;
pthread_create(..., (void *)(intptr_t)newsockfd)
```

```
void * handler(void * argument)
{
    int sockfd = (int)(intptr_t)argument;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Additionally, pulling `newsockfd` up to a wider scope is not a satisfactory solution, because that would still leave the possibility that its value is modified by acceptance of another connection before the new thread has a chance to read the value it was intended to use.

Comment: But you could have an array of per-thread resources at a larger scope, passing the index to the thread using one of the techniques shown.

Answer (score 4):

`newsockfd` is a local to the loop and you send a pointer to it to the thread, but the pointer will be invalid at the end of the loop, which comes right after `pthread_create`.

```c
for(;;)
{
    int newsockfd = accept(...);
    pthread_create(..., (void *)&newsockfd);
} // <- here &newsockfd is a "dangling" pointer
```

In the thread `int sockfd = *((int *)argument);` is therefore not guaranteed to work.

You need to store the socket descriptor permanently so that the pointer to it stays valid - or synchronize the the access to it by not letting it go out of scope until the thread has confirmed that it has read the value.

Another workaround is to cast the `int` to a `void*` and by doing so passing the file descriptor to `pthread_create` by value:

```
pthread_create(..., (void *)(uintptr_t)newsockfd);

void *handler(void * argument) {
    int sockfd = (uintptr_t)argument;
    //
}
```